# tail attribute isnt working, i need assistance getting it to work in my functions,

Tags: python

In my code I have to add a tail attribute to a linked list. The tail attribute should always be pointing to the last node in the linked list. I also have to change my append func to take the tail attribute rather than the head attribute(which points to the first node in the linked list).

```
def append(self, item):
    current = self.head
    if current:
        while current.get_next() != None:
            current = current.get_next()
        current.set_next(Node(item))
    else:
        self.head = Node(item)
```

This is my original code.

This is the code I tried.

```
def append(self, item):
    current = self.tail
    if current:
        current = current.set_next(item)
        self.tail = current
    else:
        self.tail = Node(item)
```

This code did not work, while it gave no errors all the test codes that I ran did not print anything.

```
class Node:


    def __init__(self, node_data):
       self._data = node_data
        self._next = None

    def get_data(self):

        return self._data

    def set_data(self, node_data):

        self._data = node_data

    data = property(get_data, set_data)

    def get_next(self):

        return self._next

    def set_next(self, node_next):

        self._next = node_next

    next = property(get_next, set_next)

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self._data)

class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None


    def append(self, item):
        current = self.tail
        if current:
            while current.get_next() != None:
                current = current.get_next()
            current = current.set_next(Node(item))
        else:
            self.tail = Node(item)
```

This is the code. What do I need to change about the append function for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

If the `tail` attribute always points at the end of the list, you don't need to iterate in order to find the last node; the `while` loop is unnecessary, but it should also be a no-op.

The problem you might be running into is that the `head` needs to be set when you append the first node; otherwise your `is_empty` method will always return `True`, and any code that tries to iterate through starting at `head` will never find any of your list nodes.

This seems like it should work:

```
    def append(self, item):
        if self.tail:
            # Append new node after the current tail.
            # The new node becomes the new tail.
            self.tail.set_next(Node(item))
            self.tail = self.tail.get_next()
        else:
            # The new node becomes the only node in the list.
            self.head = self.tail = Node(item)
```